# a c programming question

Tags: c

all. I am not sure whether it is appropriate to ask such a 'simple' question here, but actually it's hard for me :[ , and here is the question and a bit of c code:

```
main()
{
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        printf("%d", i);
    if (c == '\n')
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

After executing this program, when I input, say, "abc\n", the program will return:

```
0
1
2
3
```

I wondered why the result is not

```
0
1
2
```

since when c == '\n', there are no statement that increments i by 1. This is what I thought, I must be wrong, would you tell me where I was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When I ran your program, entered 'abc', the output was '0123'

Comment: Sorry, It is my fault. The output of the program should be '0123'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of operations in the `for` loop are:

```
i = 0
(c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' // c is set to 'a'
printf("%d", i)    // displays 0

++i   // i == 1
(c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' // c is set to 'b'
printf("%d", i)    // displays 1

++i   // i == 2
(c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' // c is set to 'c'
printf("%d", i)    // displays 2

++i   // i == 3
(c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' // c is set to '\n'
// the loop exits
```

So the `printf()` that's after the `for` loop prints the most recent value for `i`, which is 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `++i` gets executed *after* the `c == '\n'` case.

Perhaps this code would help clarify?

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

At the end of the loop, i will be 4, because of that final increment.

Comment: Actually, the `++i` that increments `i` to 3 gets executed just *before* `c` gets set to `'\n'` by the `getchar()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with pre increment of index variable i. In stead of pre increment, use post increment i.e. i++ inside the for loop.The reason behind that is due to pre increment. When the condition inside the loop halts, the value stored in i is already 4 when you use pre increment.

```
main()
{
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        printf("%d", i);
    if (c == '\n')
        printf("%d", i);
}
```